# How to iterate to next value in if else loop using pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas

I have to create a column in my dataset, and fill it with either 1 or -1,

the things I have to check are:

1. 1 if next day's price(Close) is greater than present day's.
2. (-1) if next day's price(Close) is less than present day's.

The pseudocode for what I have to do is:

i.e. `Action [ i ] = 1 if Close[ i+1 ] > Close[ i ]`

i.e. `Action [ i ] = (-1) if Close[ i+1 ] < Close[ i ]`

I can't seem to be able to implement this using Pandas/Numpy.
I have tried to use **np.where** inside a for loop like this.

```py
dset2['Action'] = np.nan
action = dset2['Action'].values
close = dset2['Close'].values

def fill_action(close):
    for i in range(close):
        np.where(Close[i+1] > Close[i])
        return 1
        np.where(Close[i+1] < Close[i])
        return -1
dset['Action'] = dset.apply(fill_action,axis =1)
```

I am getting the error **Series Object cannot be interpreted as integer**
The main problem I have is that I can't find how to check for the next value of a row using pandas/numpy. i.e 
**Close[i+1] & Close[i]**

Comment: why are you using `np.where` to compare singular values?

Comment: I thought I could use **np.where** for singular values, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming each row represents a day's data,

```
df['Action'] = np.where(df['price'].shift() > df['price'], 1, -1)
```